# How to specify Bayesian mixed effects model in BUGS

Tags: regression, bayesian, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, logistic

I posted this earlier in the week then retracted the question when I found a good source, not wanting to waste people's time. I haven't made much progress I'm afraid. In trying to be a good citizen here I will make the problem as clear as possible. I suspect there will be few takers.

I have a dataframe in R I wish to analyse in BUGS or R. It is in long format. It consists of multiple observations on 120 individuals, with a total of 885 rows. I am examining the occurrence of a categorical outcome -  but that's not really relevant here. The question is about something deeper.

The model I have been using up to here is

```
  mymodel<-gee(Category ~ Predictor 1 + Predictor 2..family=binomial(link="logit"),
  data=mydata, 
   id=Person)
```

with a marginal model essentially accounting for the clustering of patients. I then examined

```
 mymodel<-gee(Category ~ Predictor 1 + Predictor 2.. , family=binomial(link="logit"), 
  corstr = "AR-M", 
  data=mydata, id=Person)
```

in order to account for the time ordering of the observations on the individual people.

This didn't change much.

Then I tried to model them using the following set of MCMCPack commands:

```
 mymodel<-MCMCglmm(category~  Predictor1 + Predictor2..,  
 data=mydata, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

An examination of the output was thrilling, showing statistical significance for many predictors. I hailed myself as a newly converted bayesian, until I realised I hadn't accounted for repeated measures within patients.

I understand that I have to account for that. I understand that this may mean fitting a hyperprior for each individual - is that right? What form will this take in BUGS?

Here's a basic log reg model: (kudos to Kruschke, J., Indiana)

```
    model {
  for( i in 1 : nData ) {
    y[i] ~ dbern( mu[i] )
    mu[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-( b0 + inprod( b[] , x[i,] ))))
  }
  b0 ~ dnorm( 0 , 1.0E-12 )
   for ( j in 1 : nPredictors ) {
    b[j] ~ dnorm( 0 , 1.0E-12 )
  }
}
```

However, no hyperprior here for the individual.
Here's my best attempt so far at a within-individual design, accounting for repeated measures within people:

Here's Jackman's model for JAGS

```
1 model{
2 ## loop over data for likelihood
3 for(i in 1:n){
4  y[i] ~ dbern( mu[i] )
    mu[i] <- 1/(1+exp(-( b0 + inprod( b[] , x[i,] ))))
6 }
7 sigma ˜ dunif(0,20) ## prior on standard deviation
8 tau <- pow(sigma,-2) ## convert to precision
9
10 ## hierarchical model for each state’s intercept & slope
11 for(p in 1:50){
12 beta[p,1:2] ˜ dmnorm(mu[1:2],Tau[,]) ## bivariate normal
13 }
14
15 ## means, hyper-parameters
16 for(q in 1:2){
17 mu[q] ˜ dnorm(0,.0016)
```

}

Here's my bastard-child model for BUGS

```
1 model{
2 ## loop over data for likelihood
3 for(i in 1:n){
4 mu.y[i] <- alpha + beta[s[i],1] + beta[s[i],2]*(j[i]-jbar)
5 demVote[i] ˜ dnorm(mu.y[i],tau)
6 }
7 sigma ˜ dunif(0,20) ## prior on standard deviation
8 tau <- pow(sigma,-2) ## convert to precision
9
10 ## hierarchical model for each state’s intercept & slope
11 for(p in 1:120){
12 beta[p,1:2] ˜ dmnorm(mu[1:2],Tau[,]) ## bivariate normal
13 }
14
15 ## means, hyper-parameters
16 for(q in 1:2){
17 mu[q] ˜ dnorm(0,.0016)
  }
```

Can somebody let me know if I'm heading in the right direction. My understanding of this is growing, but slowly. Please be gentle. I'm a medic, not a statistic! I have used R quite a bit, but I'm new to BUGS, and new to Bayes.

Thanks,

R

Comment: 1. What's the size of n in your model? 2. whats j? a covariate, right? 3. I thought your dependent (response) variable was binary. 4. Why mu.y and demVote? 5. Fit a simple regression (not hierarchical) in  Bugs and compare with classical regression. They should be similar. And fit a quick hierarchical model in R with lmer function in lme4 pacage...

Answer (score 8):

You are (were) almost there.  Just a few comments - you don't have to make the prior for the `beta[,1:2]` parameters a joint MV normal; you can make the prior such that `beta[i,1]` and `beta[i,2]` are independent, which simplifies things (for example, no prior covariance need be specified.)  Note that doing so doesn't mean they will be independent in the posterior.

Other comments:  Since you have a constant term - `alpha` - in the regression, the components `beta[,1]` should have zero mean in the prior.  Also, you don't have a prior for `alpha` in the code.

Here's a model with hierarchical intercept and slope terms; I've tried to keep to your priors and  notation where possible, given the changes:

```
model {
  for(i in 1:n){
    mu.y[i] <- alpha + beta0[s[i]] + beta1[s[i]]*(j[i]-jbar)
    demVote[i] ~ dnorm(mu.y[i],tau)
  }

  alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.001) ## prior on alpha; parameters just made up for illustration
  sigma ~ dunif(0,20) ## prior on standard deviation
  tau <- pow(sigma,-2) ## convert to precision

  ## hierarchical model for each state’s intercept & slope
  for (p in 1:120) {
     beta0[p] ~ dnorm(0, tau0)
     beta1[p] ~ dnorm(mu1, tau1)
  }

  ## Priors on hierarchical components; parameters just made up for illustration
  mu1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001) 
  sigma0 ~ dunif(0,20)
  sigma1 ~ dunif(0,20)
  tau0 <- pow(sigma0,-2)
  tau1 <- pow(sigma1,-2)
}
```

A very useful resource for hierarchical models, including some "tricks" to speed up convergence, is [Gelman and Hill](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/).

(A little late with the answer, but may be helpful to some future questioner.)